# Cannot import other components in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Recently I start learning how to build a mobile app using React Native, which I heard it from one of my friend and I really interested in it. But now I faced error and tried to search for solutions from google but none of them could solve my problem. My problem is that when I import other components to **index.android.js** It shows error on mobile screen =>

> The development server returned response error code: 500

My components are stored in folder **android** =>
**android/app/components/Bar.js**

I imported it like this

> import Bar from './app/components/Bar';

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Bar from './app/components/Bar';
export default class ProfilePageApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <Bar />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProfilePageApp', () => ProfilePageApp);
```

**Bar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text
} from 'react-native';


 class Bar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

          <Text>Hello world</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Bar;
```

**error**

[image]

Comment: I think this has less do with es6 import and more with react server; try 


```
$ watchman watch-del-all
$ rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-packager-*
$ npm install
$ npm start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how RN really works regarding the file directory convention, but I think it's pretty much the same to others like React. But when I read your code I think you're missing the `./android` on your `import` statement.

You mentioned:

> My components are stored in folder android =>
>   android/app/components/Bar.js

But you imported it like so:

```
import Bar from './app/components/Bar';
```

Have you tried

```
import Bar from './android/app/components/Bar';
```

?